# HTTPClient (commons-io-1.3.2) - Invalid header: charset=iso-8859-1

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm making a HTTPGet request (Android app) and get this error.
What does it mean and how do I fix it?
Thanks!

```
E/Client  ( 3778): Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid header: charset=iso-8859-1
E/Client  ( 3778):      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeaders(AbstractMessageParser.java:162)
E/Client  ( 3778):      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:178)
E/Client  ( 3778):      at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
E/Client  ( 3778):      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
E/Client  ( 3778):      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
E/Client  ( 3778):      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
E/Client  ( 3778):      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
E/Client  ( 3778):      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421)
E/Client  ( 3778):      at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
E/Client  ( 3778):      ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `charset` listed as a request header, `Accept-Charset` is listed.

See [HTTP Request headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html)